# Taking the average rating of each movie genre in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is a node movie and there are three properties in this movie node which are `ratings`, `genre` and `releaseyear`. I would like to take the average rating of each genre. How should I go about doing that? The following is what I have:

```
MATCH(m:Movie)
WHERE m.release_year < 2010
WITH collect(m.genre) as genre, avg(m.ratings) as rating
RETURN genre, rating
ORDER BY rating
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it, but your `collect()` is throwing it off. In order for the `avg()` aggregation to compute per genre, you need each genre on its own line, no collection (what it's computing now is the average of all those movies regardless of genre). Aggregations are performed per the non-aggregation variables present on the WITH or RETURN where the aggregation is taking place:

```
MATCH(m:Movie)
WHERE m.release_year < 2010
WITH m.genre as genre, avg(m.ratings) as rating
RETURN genre, rating
ORDER BY rating
```